# WP Как создать новую запись из своей формы

Tags: wordpress

Есть форма, нужно чтобы данные из этой формы направлялись в новую запись (на утверждение).

Как мне получить данные из этой формы и создать новую запись WordPress?

Какие должны быть шаги?

```html
<form class="form-group" id="post-form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<!-- Пресса -->
<h2>Преса</h2>

<label for="name">Назва газети</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="" class="form-control">

<br>
<label for="file">Завантажити матеріал(png, jpeg, jpg, не більше 5мб)</label>
<br>
<input type="file" name="file" value="">
<br><br>

<label for="editor">Хто був редактором (якщо відомо)</label>
<input type="text" name="editor" value="" class="form-control">
<br>

<label for="type">Рівень</label>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="central" value="option1" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
    Центральний
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="local" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
    Місцевий
  </label>
</div>

<div class="additional-form">

 <label for="region">Область</label>
 <input type="text" name="region" class="form-control">

 <label for="city">Населенний пункт</label>
 <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control">

 <br>
 <textarea name="textarea" rows="2" cols="80" value="" placeholder="Короткий опис" class="form-control" resize="none"></textarea>

 <label for="date">Дата (опціонально)</label>
 <input type="date" name="date" value="" class="form-control">
</div>

<br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="" value="Відправити">

</form>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код вашей формы

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Выкинуть это всё и использовать готовые плагины.

Comment: Какие можете посоветовать на бесплатной основе?

Answer (score 1):

**Алгоритм действий:**

1. Доработать форму: добавить в нее одноразовое поле (nonce), данные должны отправляться POST-запросом (добавьте `method="POST"` к тегу `<form>`).

   Подробнее про nonce:
   [Using Nonces](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/)
   [Что такое одноразовые числа (nonces) в WordPress](https://sebweo.com/ru/chto-takoye-odnorazoviye-chisla-nonces-v-wordpress/)
2. Обработка данных формы.
   После отправки формы, данные будут содержаться в массиве `$_POST`.
   **Самое важное:** не доверять никаким данным, пришедшим от посетителя. Каждое поле должно очищаться и проверяться, перед тем как данные будут использованы.

   Подробнее про очистку и валидацию данных:
   [Data Sanitization/Escaping](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/)
   [Data Validation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-validation/)
3. Создание записи.
   Для создания новой записи используйте функцию `wp_insert_post()`.
   Подробнее о функции `wp_insert_post()`: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_insert_post

Пример кода можно посмотреть здесь: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15283/i-am-trying-to-create-a-simple-frontend-form-for-posting

Ну и, если, конечно, вам нужен результат здесь и сейчас, есть масса плагинов для создания форм. Один из лучших [Contact From 7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).